# Bluemix NodeJS ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, getaddrinfo

I have a bluemix node js application which communicates with a server. I have test and production environment. On the development environment we communicate to the test server, and I get a node js error.

When I change the server URL to the production server everything is ok.

When I run the app on localhost and connect to the test server everything is ok too.

So my problem is only on bluemix environment with communication to my company test server. Error is:

```
{
  "code": "ENOTFOUND",
  "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
  "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
  "hostname": "www.xxxxxxxxx.cz"
}
```

Hostname in error is masked.

Comment: Is your host behind a firewall?

Comment: no, I haven't problem to connect to server from my mobile application (mobile data), or from localhost running on my home LAN.

Comment: Is your server started on bluemix for bluemix to connect to?

Comment: could you please post your code and output of `cf logs <appname> --recent`?

Answer (score 2):

From the exception, I think the failing code is doing a dns lookup. I wrote this sample code and found that the error is similar or same.

```
var dns = require('dns');
dns.lookup('non-existent server', function(e, a) {
 console.log(e);
});
```

And the output is:

```
bash-4.1$ node h.js
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND non-existent server]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'non-existent server' }
bash-4.1$
```

Problem determination steps would be:

1. ping your target server from a machine which has outbound access - to make sure the server is present. If not, resolve that problem.
2. Logon to bluemix debug console
3. ping your target server. If it does not respond, there is a wall between bluemix and the target. If it responds, try this test case. If that too works, we will have to debug further, I can be of further help.

Bluemix debug console is obtained through:

1. Export an environment variable "BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE" with value "shell"
2. Restage the app.
3. Login into the web shell in browser at https://your-app-url/bluemix-debug/shell/ using your Bluemix user credentials

Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is probably in DNS on Bluemix (do you know whether bluemix use private DNS server or some public?)
When I switch my hostname to test server IP address everything goes right. But this is not good solution.
Can I manually set some DNS provider in bluemix? Or do you know whether bluemix require valid DNSSEC, because my test server hasn't DNSSEC.
Thank you

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know the answer. Bluemix leverages CloudFoundry framework, and cf has means to configure your DNS choices, please see: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#domains-dns